# ID cannot be found

Tags: android, layout

I have created an Activity containing a FrameLayout with the ID "container", though I cannot refer to this view, I have tested it in a simple reference:

activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="app.chrono.name.LoginActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(current);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new LoginFragment()); //container is written in red
}
```

I do not understand why this container cannot be refered to. It should be accessible. It is written in red and seems to not exist.

Comment: app.chrono.-.LoginActivity is thius the issue?

Comment: `tools:context="app.chrono.-.LoginActivity">` why there is a '-' letter? also, there is 3 FrameLayout  being opened but 2 being closed. resolve them first.

Comment: post the activity layout as it really is. Wht you posted in your question makes no sense. Also what `I cannot refer to this view` really means?

Comment: I just removed the app name, this does not matter at all. Secondly, why need the whole activity, theres just the class around it, nothing else. The "container" view / frame layout does not even seem to exist. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right,
Click on the line that is below your code findviewbyid and one suggestion comes press alt+enter that's all.
Also try to invalidate cache and restart :
Go to file and invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: When I try to alt enter "container" it tells me to create a new value resource.

Answer (score 0):

Container is a view but in specific it is a layout view i.e FrameLayout.

So change the type to FrameLayout instead of View.

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
```

**EDIT:**
Also if you find first solution not working add the id directly in the fragment transition like this.

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new LoginFragment());
```

Comment: It cannot find container itself. It is written in red.

Answer (score 0):

You should `commit();` your fragment transaction.

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(current);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new LoginFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: This does not give a solution. The problem is the container. It does not seem to exist and is written in red.

Answer (score 0):

First remove this line from your code

```
container = findViewById(R.id.container);
```

Use this function for opening fragment

```
 public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.remove(current);
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new LoginFragment());
  }
```

and call in onCreate like this

```
loadFragment(new LoginFragment());
```

And make sure you import these

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```